# Upstart restart process time

Tags: upstart

A question about upstart.

I understand the restart command does a stop and restart of the process.
What happens if the process will not stop and check for the signals for a long time (20min or 2h)?

Will it still restart after such a long time ?

Example my-process:

```
until stop_signal_received
  work for 2h
end
```

So the script will check for stop signals every 2 hours.

```
$sudo restart my-process
```

Will the process restart after 2 hours or not?

Comment: It depends on how the script that does the restart is written.

Comment: I added an example.